# can a UITableViewCell be the delegate for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, uicollectionview

I want to set a `UICollectionView` inside a `UITabelViewCell`

So far, I encountered 2 approaches:
1. The main `ViewController` is the delegate for all, and we use tags
http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/

2. The `UICollectionView` sits inside a a view which is his delegate
   http://devblog.orgsync.com/2013/04/26/creating_scrolling_filmstrip_within_uitableview/

My question is - can I have approach 2 but skip the extra view and have the UITableViewCell be the delegate?

Comment: Your actual question conflicts with your question title - do you want your UITableView or your UITableViewCell to be the delegate?

Comment: I want the UITableViewCell to be the delegate of the UICollectionView inside it

Comment: Yes this can be achieved if you are using custom cells but I am not sure about UITableViewCell in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just extend the `UITableViewCell` but beware because the cells are recycled in the table view therefore also the `UICollectionView` will be.

Comment: hmm... good point. Actually I'm doing option 1, although it seems "complicated" - using a tag is quite elegant actually